# Parse XML stored in SQL row - MS SQL Sever

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have a table (user_table) with 10 users and one of the column has name "XML_PATH".
The XML_PATH contains XML file which looks like this :

```
<Column>
         <Column Name="user_time_zone" DataType="String">GMT</Column>
         <Column Name="user_time_type" DataType="String">24hrs</Column>
         ...
         <Column Name="user_time_country" DataType="String">India</Column>
</Column>
```

I need to know if it is possible for me to write an SQL query and get USER_TIME_TYPE node's value as a result.

Comment: Please dont spam TAGS, they are there to attract the correct audience, if you use irrelevant tags you get irrelevant visitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [XPATH](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). Example:

```
DECLARE @Value XML = '
<Column>
         <Column Name="user_time_zone" DataType="String">GMT</Column>
         <Column Name="user_time_type" DataType="String">24hrs</Column>
         <Column Name="user_time_country" DataType="String">India</Column>
</Column>
'

SELECT @Value.query('/Column/Column[@Name=''user_time_type'']/text()')
```

Output:

> 24hrs

If the column type is XML you can use the [query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) method to perform XPATH queries on the column.
To test you XPATH expression you can use [XPath tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/94722/0)

If you have column you can simply do the following:

```
SELECT XML_DATA.query('/Column/Column[@Name=''user_time_type'']/text()')
FROM user_date
```

Or if the column type is not XML

```
SELECT cast(XML_DATA as XML).query('/Column/Column[@Name=''user_time_type'']/text()')
FROM user_date
```

Comment: This does not meet the requirement, I have a column it ( select XML_DATA from user_date), this XML_DATA has 10 entries (Since 10 users in user_data table). These 10 entries are having XML format in each. I tired using DECLARE @Value XML = (select XML_DATA from user_table) then  SELECT @Value.query('/Column/Column[@Name=''user_time_type'']/text()'), it is saying returned more than 1 value, which is true because I have more than 1 entries (10 to be exact)

Answer (score 1):

Though this question is already answered, here is a much cleaner solution.

Combination of `.nodes()` and `.value()` XQuery methods provides the exact answer with a specified data type.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<Column>
         <Column Name="user_time_zone" DataType="String">GMT</Column>
         <Column Name="user_time_type" DataType="String">24hrs</Column>
         <Column Name="user_time_country" DataType="String">India</Column>
</Column>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT c.value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS user_time_type
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/Column/Column[@Name="user_time_type"]') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----------------+
| user_time_type |
+----------------+
| 24hrs          |
+----------------+
```